# How to make a field into a required field if condition is met?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, validation

In adding an item to the list/library. I want to make **Actual(Hrs)** field required if only the **Status** input is **Completed**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tried the above code with the Category field when it is "Meeting", if Meeting is chosen than the All Day Event must not be empty
**=IF(Category="Meeting",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([All Day Event]))),TRUE)**
When I tried to save this error came up
***One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.*** Help please

Comment: Try validate it in Presaveaction ..https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the below text in List Validation settings. You check your field name properly while keeping the validation `Status`, `Actual(Hrs)`

`=IF(Status="Completed",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Actual(Hrs)]))),TRUE)`

Validation message `Actual(Hrs) should not be blank`

Comment: I thought that column validation can not be based on other columns.

Comment: not column Validation, there is a list `Validation settings` under list settings. Please look at it.

Comment: Woow thats a good and new feature for me :) Thank you.

Comment: can you vote if this works for you :)

Comment: check your list column names properly. `Status`, `Actual(Hrs)`. may be some space or any other characters exist. I can see in the screen shot `Actuals (hrs)`. change this in the formulae

Comment: Can I also apply these if I want 2 fields became a required field if the Status is complete?

Comment: Yes you can make it. This formulas like excel formulas. you can google for IF,nested IF, And,OR conditions